# Permissions error on FSO DeleteFile/MoveFile

Tags: file-io, permissions, fso

I'm trying to delete/move a file using classic asp fso but I'm getting this error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Permission denied
```

The file is located in `c:\files\test\file.txt` and ultimately I want to move it to `c:\archive\file.txt`

I started out with **Move** but I got the error. Then I split it up into **Copy** and **Delete**. The copying went fine but still the same error on **Delete**.

I ruled out the **Delete** method because I was able to use **Delete** on the file in the 'archive' folder using this code:

```
dim fs,f
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set f=fs.GetFile("C:\archive\file.txt")
f.Delete
set f=nothing
set fs=nothing
```

I also double-checked the permissions on both folders and they're exactly the same for IIS_IUSRS: Read&Execute, List folder contents, Read, Write are checked. I tried giving Modify rights as well but that made no difference.

Finally, I checked the file's attributes and it came back as 32 (Archive). I also tried to force the delete:

```
fso.DeleteFile FileName, true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS_USRS folder permissions had to specifically include 'Delete' from the 'Advanced' dialog in Windows.